# How to make query with order by with current date

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to join 2 tables and want to show latest post first based on current date for example today's publish post will show at top then future date then past date's post will show. I need to write this query in sequelize. I am getting unknown column error 'postModel.DATE(published_at)' My sequelize query is like that -

```
postModel.findAndCountAll({
               include:[
                { model:userModel, 
                  where: { user_id:  user_id},
                  required:false
                  },
                ],
                order: [
                   [ 'DATE(published_at) = DATE(NOW())', 'DESC']
                ],
                limit: limit,
                offset: offset,
                      
        });
```

Following raw query is working well to me

```
SELECT * FROM posts as P JOIN user as U ON U.id = P.user_id
where
ORDER BY
    DATE(P.published_at)=DATE(NOW()) DESC,
    DATE(P.published_at)<DATE(NOW()) DESC,
    DATE(P.published_at)>DATE(NOW()) ASC`
```

Answer (score 0):

remove your date function and query like this .

```
postModel.findAndCountAll({
  include: [{ model: userModel, where: { user_id: user_id },required:false }],
  where: {
    published_at: {
      [Op.eq]: Date(NOW()),
    },
  },
  order: [["published_at", "DESC"]],
  limit: limit,
  offset: offset,
});
```

Comment: I already tried it, it is also not working
 it will say -"Unknown column 'posts.published_at = DATE(NOW())' in 'order clause'",

Comment: no that is not a solution, I need to sorting data not filtering